# What is the `ServerName` attribute for apache2 and what does it do?

Tags: apache2, webserver

I do not know what this config setting means. Does it mean that it registers a domain name?
Is it like DNS?

Here is what I have for my apache2 default config

ServerName staugie.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

also, is there any way to register a free domain through the apache foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerName` is just the internal name for your webpage. When some client talks to your Webserver it passes in the header what address is actually looking for but by no means people will find you just with that. For that are DNS.

> 1. You type "http://www.example.com" into your browser.
> 2. Your computer **asks its DNS resolver** which IP address it should use when it wants to talk to www.example.com.
> 3. Your computer connects to that IP address, and says that it wants to talk to www.example.com (that's the `Host:`header in HTTP).
> 4. The webserver looks at its configuration to figure out what to do with a request for content from www.example.com. Any one of the
>      following may happen:
>
>    - www.example.com is listed as a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` for a `VirtualHost` - if so, then it will use the configuration for that
>        VirtualHostto deliver the content.
>    - The server doesn't have any VirtualHosts at all - if so, then it will use the configuration in its httpd.conf to deliver the content.
>    - The server has VirtualHosts but www.example.com isn't listed in any of them - if so, the first Virtualhost in the list will be used to
>        deliver the content.

<sub>[Taken from Jennen D answer at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/520201/180142)</sub>

> Does it mean that it registers a domain name? Is it like DNS?

No, no.

> is there any way to register a free domain through the apache foundation?

No. You must pay.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.